# Swift- Adjusting Constraints to allow for keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, tableview

I'm a new SWIFT programmer learning to code as a hobby.  I'm near done my first app and have a tableview in which part of the cell contains a textfield where the user can edit the data contained therein.

When the user clicks in the textfield, the keyboard pops up and obscures much of the tableview.

I've researched this and have been studying for the last hour the realm of solutions, but I'm a little stuck on where to start.  As best I can tell, I should just adjust the constraint on tableview such that it isn't 0 from the bottom of the view but rather how many ever pixels it is that is the height of the keyboard.

So I understand the concept but don't know how to execute these 2 big parts:

1. how do I set up a listener so that when the keyboard appears I can run some code
2. how do I programmatically set the constraints of my tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to attach some observers in your viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Remember to remove them in viewWillDisappear:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

You'll need an @objc function for your observer to call:

```
@objc private func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = (notification as Notification).userInfo, let value = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }
    
    if ((userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue) != nil {
        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
        var newHeight: CGFloat
        let textHeight = inputTextView.textContainer.size.height
        
        if isKeyboardShowing {
            newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            bottomConstraint.constant = newHeight + textHeight
            view.bringSubviewToFront(messageInputContainerView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0,
                               options: .curveEaseOut,
                               animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                               completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            view.bringSubviewToFront(messageInputContainerView) 
            newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            bottomConstraint?.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + messageInputContainerView.bounds.height - textHeight
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0,
                           delay: 0,
                           options: .curveEaseOut,
                           animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                           completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

`bottomConstraint` is your class reference here in this case attached to the bottom of the tableView on storyboard and is our movable baseline when the keyboard is open and closed. You will need to tweak the values and constraint choices for your own use case/sizes. `messageInputContainerView` is the container for our `inputTextView` in this example.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you very much!!

Comment: could you explain that messageInputContainerView a little bit more?  I'm confused by that and don't know how to adapt my code to that piece.

Comment: @LinusBicker messageInputContainerView is a UIView that holds inputTextView which is an UITextView. I also have a send button in the messageInputContainerView in my use case, so it moves everything up at once by attaching the constraint to the parent view.

Comment: so I have a UIVIew that I dragged into my view controller as an IBOutlet from storyboard and I renamed that messageInputContainerView just for the sake of keeping it same was what you have. That view contains all of my relevant UI structure and is the view I want to adjust the bottom constraint on when the keyboard appears. I couldn't get your code to work but I am trying this -

Comment: let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.messageInputContainerView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant:-500)
                
view.addConstraints([verticalConstraint])

Comment: but I can't seem to get that to work either.  I tried change the view.addConstraints to messageInputContainerView.addConstraints and it tries to execute the code when he keyboard appears but I get an error about not being able to apply constraint where there is reference to external source or something like that

Comment: @LinusBicker also include a reference to your `bottomConstraint` from your storyboard to your ViewController and only adjust the constraint by calling `bottomConstraint.constant = newHeight` and that tidies up that piece of code and keeps it in one place to adjust.

Comment: Ok. I’ll try again. I was getting an error that bottomConstraint was not recognized when I initially tried.

Comment: I figured it out.  I didn't realize I had to add an iboutlet to the constraint , thus creating that bottomConstraint variable. thank you very much!!!